# Is the upgrade to 4.1 worth it?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone, upgrade

I currently have a jailbroken 3Gs iPhone running 4.01.

I've really used the jailbroken part, but it's good to know that I can tether my laptop to the phone should I ever need to.

Having said that, is it worth it to upgrade the phone to 4.1 (which hasn't been jailbroken yet)?  Does it fix the sluggishness issues that were caused by the upgrade from iPhone OS 3.x to iOS 4.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been no reported issues with sluggishness on the iPhone 3GS.
The issues with sluggishness relate to the iPhone 3G. The update to iOS 4.1 resolves these issues.

Comment: 4.1 *doesn't* resolve those issues, in all cases at least, my old 3G was a testament to that. (Though I've compared it to a way less sluggish 3G, so I guess it depends on things like what you've got installed on the phone.) But you're right about 3GS.

Comment: 3Gs also has sluggishness issues.  There is an office full of people with 3Gs here who are testament to it.  The issues are not as bad as 3G, but they do exist.  Switching from app to app is slower.  The iPod part is slower to move between podcasts.  These are just few of the issues.

Comment: Just to follow up, I did upgrade to 4.1 and it did resolve some issues with the iPod sluggishness.